# Checkbox inside clickable div does not get checked- Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/9uoqxfz7).
In this fiddle, I have a checkbox inside a clickable div marked in red background. When you click on div/ the checkbox, id of div is logged on the console.

**HTML**

```
<div id="vm">
  <div class="myDIv" id="MyDiv" data-bind="click : function() 
      {$root.clicked(event)}" style="width : 50px; height : 50px; background-color : red;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : attribute" value="checkbox-1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MyViewModel(){
    this.attribute = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.clicked = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.currentTarget.id); 
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Here, the checkbox does not get checked or unchecked when I click on it. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Not used to KO... But you will need another click handler for the checkbox with a [`e.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) inside... To prevent the event on the checkbox to propagate to its parent.

Comment: Please, have a look to this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30629327/4065876

Comment: What you want is to have the checkbox checked/unchecked when the user clicks inside the given div? I mean why whould the checkbox be checked, you are not "selecting" anything on it with your current code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9uoqxfz7/27/ try this one as an example

Comment: @MKougiouris, I don't want to check the checkbox when I click on div.My problem is, checkbox (enclosed in a clickable div) does not get checked when clicked on itself. In your example, you have removed the click event of the enclosing div. That will obviously work.

Comment: @JoseLuis: That didn't work.

Comment: @VinitDivekar This is the proper way to go about it. if you want to to other stuff when the checkbox is clicked you can .subscribe(function(v){ doThis() }) on the observable itself

Comment: @VinitDivekar The same question as yours: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912525/change-checkbox-value-on-parent-div-click.  :-)

Comment: @JoseLuis: I had seen that question before. Thanks for sharing though. But I could not replace my div tag with label tag as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @VinitDivekar Oh, I'm sorry, I see now in a comment that you don't want the checkbox value is changed when you click in the div.  I was thinking the opposite.  It could be nice to update your question in order to say that you only need to log a message.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `return true;` in the HTML code as follows:

```
<div class="myDIv" id="MyDiv" data-bind="click : function(){$root.clicked(event); return true;}" style="width : 50px; height : 50px; background-color : red;">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : attribute" value="checkbox-1"/>
</div>
```

See, this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/9uoqxfz7/63/).

I was particularly interested in the `event` object hence I had to write the `click` event as `click : function(){$root.clicked(event)}`

if you do not need `event` object, the click event can be written as:

```
<div class="myDIv" id="MyDiv" data-bind="click : clicked" style="width : 50px; height : 50px; background-color : red;">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : attribute" value="checkbox-1"/>
</div>
```

and javascript function can be written as:

```
this.clicked = function(event){
    return true;
}
```